# White Backdrop appears when I click md-select

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, angular-material

I have this problem in some parts of my website where a white backdrop appears every time I click a dropdown(md-select) in my form. At first it occurred only on forms inside a modal but lately it affected page dropdowns as well.

I observed the behavior of css every time I clicked a dropdown and this is what I noticed: Some in-line style appears on my body tag during click.

```
<body id="#background" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: -718.889px;">
```

No idea where did it come from. I tried to change the 'position: fixed' into 'position: inherit' on inspect element and it solved the issue. Now my problem is I don`t know where to find it in my codes.

Comment: inspect that element with firebug or simply with firefox's inbuilt option and check that it will show some event attached to it. .. you can post the link to that page so that i can check it for you

Comment: @JkAlombro Did you find any solution to this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem.
Solved it by adding `top: 0px` to the container of the div that holds the elements that gets white blocks during clicking of the dropdown.